# Videoplayer in Android?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

give me some simple example for streaming video player.

i got a error in api demo.

Error is:

```
Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info PVMFErrCorrupt android
```

thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This error occurs due to data
>   corruption being detected. A typical
>   example is when an invalid media
>   stream is encountered in datapath.

(from [here](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/cupcake/external/opencore/doc/pvmf_return_codes.pdf))

Hence, your problem is probably not with your code, but with what you are trying to stream.

Comment: hey but the link working in system browser perfectly... why it can't be??

Comment: The link in the answer doesn't link to anything related. Where is it supposed to go?

Comment: @Rachel: That was a link to a PDF file that no longer appears to be online -- sorry.